# Why my WebGL2 app dosen't work on win browsers?

Tags: javascript, graphics, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to finish an assignment of my CG course. I chose this [repo](https://github.com/wulinjiansheng/WebGL_PathTracer/tree/master) as reference. I refactored most of the code, migrated to WebGL2 and added BVH structure from scratch to optimize object intersection and support complex triangular objects (.obj files). This is the current code: [repo](https://github.com/YigesMx/WebGL-Path-Tracing).

I did these on my mbp(14' m2 pro) and it works smoothly, but when I tested it on my(and my friends') windows laptops, it just throw 'context loss' error. It's weird because the webgl contexts will crush over the whole browsers until I restart the browser completely. Otherwise, if I just refresh the tab, it won't be able to initialize webgl context anymore.

After some debugging, I found that it can still work when I only keep 1~6 simple objects(sphere, cube, plane, etc.) in scene or only one mesh in scene.

I thought it was because of the RAM but I found it only occupies 300M. As for the fact that it can run well on my mac(both Edge and Safari), I think that my code doesn't have any critical error. So I assume it was caused by the browsers and platform or some other bugs in my code.

How can I figure out this? Or anyone can help?

=== further investigation ===

When I tried dubugging, I find something really odd. I wrote this somewhere (just modify `pt.frag` > `bool intersectMesh`, from `intersect.intersectPos = (meshObj.model *  vec4(tempIntersect.intersectPos, 1.0)).xyz; intersect.intersectNormal = normalize((meshObj.transInvModel * vec4(tempIntersect.intersectNormal,0.0)).xyz); intersect.intersectDistance = length(ray.origin - intersect.intersectPos);` to `intersect.intersectDistance = INF;`) in my code in order to debug (On windows of course, as everything goes well on macos):

```c
#define INF_F (1e6)

...

intersect.intersectDistance = INF_F;

...
```

My code just works fine. But when I used simple expression like this:

```c
#define INF_F (1e6)

...

intersect.intersectDistance = 2.0 * INF_F;

...
```

The browser will crash as I described above.

I also tried const expression `const float INF_F = 1e6;` but the result remains the same.

I didn't even actually use `intersect.intersectDistance` after that line at all.

However, in other places use all most the same expression (like other `xxx_xxx.intersectDistance = INF_F;`), I can still use 2.0 to mult, It's just odd!

What's that mean? Is it actually a problem of platform?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not suited for stackoverflow as it's too broad, the relevant code needs to be included in the question itself and so on. After skimming through the code I'd say look into the intersection shader, maybe it has a condition where it loops infinitely, or the ANGLE transpiler gets hung up on the way you traverse the BVH (try running chrome with `--use-gl="desktop"` flag to assess the latter).

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I got a strange result when I tried debug. I've added some information in my question. If possible, please give me some advise~ Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try comparing the translated shader code using the [`WEBGL_debug_shaders` extension](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_debug_shaders/). Please report back with any findings.